# Admin CMD through SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, cmd.exe, administrator

I have freeSSHD set up on my Windows computer, and I use my Linux laptop to connect through SSH. However, when I SSH into my Windows computer and try to run a custom Batch script that requires admin privileges, it will not run. How can I get the SSH server on my Windows computer to run commands through admin CMD?

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: When I try to run my custom Batch script that starts oclHashcat I get the error `Error: oclHashcat.induct: Permission denied`

Comment: What user is freeSHHD running as? When you ssh into your server, what does `whoami` say?

Comment: freeSSHD is running as my account `Joe` on the Windows computer. This account is an administrator. I tired to use the system service, but whenever I start the service, freeSSHD cannot start the SSH server. Also when I start the freeSSHD program as administrator, or if I turn of UAC, I get a permission denied error when I try to connect to the freeSSHD server through my Linux client.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the "runas.exe" to execute your script as a user with more rights. If that does not work, you may consider reconfiguring FreeSSHD to run as a user with elevated rights. Be aware of the security implications of doing so.